# Doc Library change version history "comments" column name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SP2013 i have a document library were the Version history is enabled. the Display Name of the Comments column in Version history page i would like to Change. Is it possible ?. If so what are the ways ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code to achieve your purpose.

1. Use F12 to find the id of Comments column. You can refer to the below article to find the id(for example, mine is "id=diidVersionsSortComments"):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

2. Go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` and edit the versions.aspx file.

[image]

3. locate at `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` and under it add below jQuery:

   $(document).ready(function()
         {
                       $("#diidVersionsSortComments").text('Comments1');
        });
4. Save your changes and go to library to check the results.

Comment: full script in step 3: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
                    $("#diidVersionsSortComments").text('Comments1');
     });
 
</script>